# Can a bijection be constructed between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Can a bijection be constructed between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, such that $f:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bijective function?

I understand that there exists no bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$, and that the real numbers are not a countable set, however, since the rational numbers form a dense subset of the real numbers, I wondered if some bijective function might exist?

Comment: No, you can't. Google "Cardinality of sets"

Comment: Here is the prove of the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is [uncountable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Numbers_are_Uncountable)

Comment: [Please](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10337/are-there-many-more-rational-numbers-than-integers) [search](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40728/why-does-cantors-diagonal-argument-not-work-for-rational-numbers) [the](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180550/why-is-the-cardinality-of-irrational-numbers-greater-than-rational-numbers) [site](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499607/why-does-cantors-proof-that-r-is-uncountable-fail-for-q) before posting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. One may prove that [$\Bbb Q$ is countable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Rational_Numbers_are_Countably_Infinite) while [$\Bbb R$ is uncountable](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Numbers_are_Uncountable). Hence there is no bijection $\Bbb Q\to\Bbb R$.

Topological spaces containing a countably dense subspace are interesting enough that they have earned a name. Spaces with this property are called [separable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_space).